# How to diagnose the cause of losing connections in WLAN?

Tags: connection, wireless-networking, diagnostic

Recently I brought my laptop from my work to my appartment. At work the laptop works perfectly in WLAN, but at home I have the following problems with WLAN:

- When streaming movie from YouTube, the movie gets buffered only to a certain point. Then the buffering process stops. I'm usually able to trigger streaming again by either reopening the site or by starting streaming from yet unbuffered part of the movie.
- Sending mails from Web mailbox often exceeds sending timeout and then fails
- Web sites download slowly or some of the does not at all at the first request

**How can I fix the problem or at least start diagnosing the cause?**

**Narrowing down the problem**

I am far from being telecommunication expert, but I tried to narrow down the problem and I found that:

- WiFi signal strenght is stable (from system tray)
- Problems occurs only to my laptop (4 other laptos at our appartment work fine)
- Problem occurs in different locations of my home, both close and far from the access point
- When I connect to the router by cable, the connection is perfect
- When I switch to a different WLAN (of some neighbour), the problem remains, but might be for another reason (weaker signal?)

I had similar problem with another laptop at home and it disappeared once I set up transmit power of its WiFi card to the max. In the newest laptop this trick did not help at all.

**Technical details**

- OS: Windows 7
- Wireless card: Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
- Router: Sitecom WL-612
- WLAN security: WPA-Personal with TKIP encryption

Comment: You may want to upgrade the firmware on your router and drivers on your wireless NIC. If this doesn't help then scan for the channels and see if you're using a popular one. If so, configure your router to use a different channel.